# Snake game collision with tail

Tags: c++, sfml, stdvector

I'm having a problem with the **TailCollision** function in my snake game. Right now it doesn't work at all. Other than that the snake is drawn and moves perfectly. Thanks in advance to whoever points out where i goofed ^-^

Em i'm new to sfml and using a vector... pretty much my first time so please don't be too harsh!

Here is my Snake.cpp

```
#include "Snake.h"


Snake::Snake(){

    Snakey.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10, 10));

    Snakey.setFillColor(sf::Color(0,255,0));


    enter code here
    Snakey.setPosition(180,60);

    BodyList.push_back(Body);

}


Snake::~Snake(){
    BodyList.clear();
}

void Snake::Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window){

    window.draw(Snakey);

    for (sf::RectangleShape& Body : BodyList){

    window.draw(Body);
    }

    BodyList.erase(BodyList.begin());
    BodyList.push_back(Body);

}

void Snake::Grow(){

    Body.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10, 10));

    Body.setFillColor(sf::Color(0,100,0));

    Body.setPosition(Snakey.getPosition().x,Snakey.getPosition().y);

    BodyList.push_back(Body);


}



void Snake::Move(sf::Event event, sf::RenderWindow &window){

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Left == event.key.code && Dir != "Right"){
        Snakey.move(-10, 0);
        Body.move(-10,0);
        Dir = ("Left");
    }

    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Key::Right == event.key.code && Dir != "Left"){
        Snakey.move(10, 0);
        Body.move(10,0);

        Dir = ("Right");
    }
    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Key::Up == event.key.code && Dir != "Down"){
        Snakey.move(0, -10);
        Body.move(0,-10);

        Dir = ("Up");
    }
    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Key::Down == event.key.code && Dir != "Up"){
        Snakey.move(0, 10);
        Body.move(0,10);

        Dir = ("Down");
    }

    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Key::Down == event.key.code && Dir == "Up" || 
        sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Key::Up == event.key.code && Dir == "Down" ||
        sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Key::Right == event.key.code && Dir == "Left"||
        sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Left == event.key.code && Dir == "Right"){

        window.close();
    }
}

void Snake::TailCollision(sf::RenderWindow &window){

    for (int i = 0 ; i < BodyList.size(); i++){
        if ((Snakey.getPosition().x == BodyList[i].getPosition().x && Snakey.getPosition().y == BodyList[i].getPosition().y)&&
            (BodyList[i].getPosition().x != BodyList.back().getPosition().x &&
            BodyList[i].getPosition().y != BodyList.back().getPosition().y)){

                window.close();

        }

    }
}


sf::RectangleShape Snake::GetShape(){
    return Snakey;
}
```

Comment: This is an excellent time to learn to use the debugger.  I would suggest a read of this https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: You demand for a collision that both x and y of `BodyList[i]` and `BodyList.back()` differ, is that what you want? Otherwise, change the `&&` to `||`.

Comment: yeah the .back() of the vector spawns in the head's position so if I changed it to | | the snake dies immediately after grow is called ^-^"

Comment: also thank you for the link!

Answer (score 1):

I think it is better to use SFML built-in functions, like `getGlobalBounds()`.
If Snakey is a `sf::Shape` subclass (I hope it is), it should work.

```
const auto & headBounds = Snakey.getGlobalBounds();
for (int i = 0 ; i < BodyList.size(); i++)
{
    const auto & bodyBounds = BodyList[i].getGlobalBounds();
    if( bodyBounds.intersects( headBounds ) 
    {
        // process collision here
        break;
    }
}
```

Or even a bit shorter, as suggested in comments:

```
const auto & headBounds = Snakey.getGlobalBounds();
if( 
    std::any_of(
            BodyList.begin()
        ,   BodyList.end()
        ,   [ headBounds ] ( const auto & body ) 
            {
                return body.getGlobalBounds().intersects( headBounds );
            }
   )
)
{
    // process collision;
}
```

Comment: The loop here can be replaced with `std::any_of(BodyList.begin(), BodyList.end(), [&](auto & body) { return body.getPosition().getGlobalBounds().intersects(headBounds); })`

Comment: @Caleth Thanks for an advice.

Comment: thank you so much! I'll try that! but my problem Is that the last vector element is always spawned in the position of the head from what I understand so as soon as grow is called the window is closed

Answer (score 0):

I've realised the problem was with my move function and not even the collision one! Thank you all and I'm sorry to waste your time! ^-^ I really goofed...

```
Snake::Snake(){

    Snakey.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10, 10));

    Snakey.setFillColor(sf::Color(0,255,0));

    Snakey.setPosition(180,60);

}


Snake::~Snake(){
    BodyList.clear();
}

void Snake::Draw(sf::RenderWindow &window){

    window.draw(Snakey);

    for (sf::RectangleShape& Body : BodyList){

    window.draw(Body);
    }

}

void Snake::Grow(){

    Body.setSize(sf::Vector2f(10, 10));

    Body.setFillColor(sf::Color(0,100,0));

    BodyList.push_back(Body);

}



void Snake::Move(sf::Event event, sf::RenderWindow &window){

    if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Left == event.key.code && Dir != "Right"){

        Body.setPosition(Snakey.getPosition().x,Snakey.getPosition().y);

        BodyList.push_back(Body);
        BodyList.erase(BodyList.begin());

        Snakey.move(-10, 0);

        Dir = ("Left");
    }

    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Key::Right == event.key.code && Dir != "Left"){

        Body.setPosition(Snakey.getPosition().x,Snakey.getPosition().y);

        BodyList.push_back(Body);
        BodyList.erase(BodyList.begin());

        Snakey.move(10, 0);

        Dir = ("Right");
    }
    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Key::Up == event.key.code && Dir != "Down"){

        Body.setPosition(Snakey.getPosition().x,Snakey.getPosition().y);        

        BodyList.push_back(Body);
        BodyList.erase(BodyList.begin());

        Snakey.move(0, -10);

        Dir = ("Up");
    }
    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Key::Down == event.key.code && Dir != "Up"){

        Body.setPosition(Snakey.getPosition().x,Snakey.getPosition().y);

        BodyList.push_back(Body);
        BodyList.erase(BodyList.begin());

        Snakey.move(0, 10);

        Dir = ("Down");
    }

    else if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Key::Down == event.key.code && Dir == "Up" || 
        sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Key::Up == event.key.code && Dir == "Down" ||
        sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Key::Right == event.key.code && Dir == "Left"||
        sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed && sf::Keyboard::Left == event.key.code && Dir == "Right"){

        window.close();
    }
}

void Snake::TailCollision(sf::RenderWindow &window){

    for (int i = 0 ; i < BodyList.size(); i++){
        if ((Snakey.getPosition().x == BodyList[i].getPosition().x && Snakey.getPosition().y == BodyList[i].getPosition().y)){

                window.close();

        }

    }
}
```